# Is A:={$x \in X : f(x) \neq g(x)$} for continuous f and g

Tags: general-topology

Let X be a topological space and f,g continuous $X  \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

Is the set defined as A:={$x \in X : f(x) \neq g(x)$} open?

I tried to proof it but I couldn't.
Would be nice if someone had a hint for me.

Comment: The inverse image of the diagonal $\Delta = \{(a,a) \in \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} : a \in \mathbb{R}\}$ by the continuous map $f\times g : X \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} $ is $X-A$. Thus $A$ is open.

Comment: Hint:  define $h(x)=f(x)-g(x)$.  What is your set in terms of $h$?

Comment: @lulu A={$x \in X: h(x) \neq 0$}, so i can write $A=h^{-1}(0)$. Now  ${0} \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is open, because  Int({0})={0}. Is this correct?

Comment: No.  $\{0\}$ is not open.  And, $A\neq h^{-1}(0)$.

Comment: @ lulu I think I got something wrong, it should be A= $h^{-1}$(X\{0})

Comment: Now X\{0} is open,thus A is open. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.